# How can i build app in release mode with grunt-cordova-cli?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, gruntjs

Now i am developing an webview app with cordova,and in my project i want to run cordova commands with **grunt-cordova-cli** to do some automatic tasks,here is my Gruntfile.js:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    clean: {
        build: ['./platforms/*/build'],
    },
    cordova_cli: {
        options: {
            projectRoot: 'app',
            cmd: 'build',
            platforms: ['ios', 'android'],
            release:true
        },
        build_ios: {
            cmd: 'build',
            platforms: ['ios']
        },
        build_android: {
            cmd: 'build',
            options:['release'],
            platforms: ['android']
        }
    }
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-clean');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-cordova-cli');
grunt.registerTask('cordova', ['cordova_cli']);

grunt.registerTask('test', function(){
    grunt.file.setBase('./');
    grunt.task.run([ 'clean:build','cordova_cli:build_android']);
});}
```

When i run `grunt test` in the command line ,the grunt worked fine,but it seems that the `cordova build android` command has worked in debug mode,because i saw the `android-debug.apk` file created by `cordova build` in the build dir.My problem is **How can i build my android app in release mode with grunt-cordova-cli?**

Comment: This question has confused me for long time,is there someone know something about it?

Comment: It's a 3 year old plugin that hasn't seen any development beyond the initial release... I'd probably find something that's more maintained.  Use grunt-exec plugin instead